# MySQL InnoDB FULLTEXT search rankings for phrase searches

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, innodb

I'm running FULLTEXT searches against an InnoDB table, looking for phrases rather than separate keywords. eg. searching for "foo bar" as a two word phrase rather than "foo" and "bar" individually.

Here is my test data:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | content                                                                       |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | example foo text bar                                                          |
|  2 | default value foo foo server                                                  |
|  3 | default value foo foo server bar foo test                                     |
|  4 | process foo bar potato integer text bar bar content foo foo value bar foo foo |
|  5 | foo bar demo string value foo bar music foo bar most foo bar                  |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And here is my test query:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(content) AGAINST ('"foo bar"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM test
WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('"foo bar"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The problem is the results:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| id | content                                                                       | score              |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|  4 | process foo bar potato integer text bar bar content foo foo value bar foo foo |  0.948742687702179 |
|  5 | foo bar demo string value foo bar music foo bar most foo bar                  | 0.8314893841743469 |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

As you can see, row 5 contains the phrase "foo bar" four times, whereas row 4 only contains it once, but row 4 is being ranked higher than 5. It looks as though the ranking is ignoring the phrase requirement.

Does anyone know how to make this work properly?

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Using InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is a quirk of phrases.  The following [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) ranks among the most inconsistent language that I've seen:

> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (") characters matches
>   only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. **The
>   full-text engine splits the phrase into words and performs a search in
>   the FULLTEXT index for the words.** Nonword characters need not be
>   matched exactly: Phrase searching requires only that matches contain
>   exactly the same words as the phrase and in the same order.

The first sentence directly conflicts with the rest of the explanation.  I've highlighted the part that I think is important.

So, I'll speculate.  MySQL does the phrase matching *at the word* level.  So, more "foo"s and "bar"s in the result -- without "foo bar" add to the score.  There is some extra mechanism that makes sure that the pair is actually in the result set, but this does not affect the score.

One thing you *could* do is your own ordering:

```
order by length(content) - length(replace(content, 'foo bar', '')) desc
```

This explicitly looks for "foo bar" in the content, ordering by that value.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected this may just be the way MySQL does it (scoring at the word level). I'm sure there are reasons for that, but it does make the ranking useless when you're searching for phrases. Thanks for the custom ranking suggestion, I will have to look into something like that instead, although it's going to impact performance (my real data is tens of thousands of rows).

Comment: @JackSleight . . . The custom ranking will only work on the matched rows, which could be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think (without any documentation reference) that the ranking is also dependent on the length of the total text.  There are a lot of things one can argue should be factored in; try not to set your expectations too high.

I tried 7 versions of MySQL/MariaDB and got 6 different sets of "scores".  So, I would strongly advise against taking any *single* score very seriously.  They did, however, rank the 4 "foo bar" cases in the same order.  (I expanded your test case to vary the length more.)